# Disable dynamically created checkbox when checked

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I have the following code which produces a list of checkboxes.  This list could contain any amount of checkboxes and will vary per record:

```html
@if (Model.PaymentRefundData != null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.PaymentRefundData.Count(); i++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].ContractContributionHistoryId)
        @Html.DisplayFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].CommencementDeductions)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].Category)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].NumberOfContributions)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].EmployeeContributionReference)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].TeamMemberName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].NotInUse, new { id= "checked" })
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

I also have this code to disable a checkbox, when it has been checked.  The problem is that it will only disable the first checkbox, I need to disable any in the list:

```
$(document).on('click', '#checked', function () {
  if ($("#checked").prop('checked', true)) {  
    $('#checked').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Thanks

Thanks to Rory & Tokunbo, both these solutions do exactly what I ask, however having implemented them, I realise that it's not going to work for me as a disabled checkbox doesn't post when I hit save.

I am now thinking that the best way to handle this it to make any checked checkboxes disabled on page load, as when I hit save, the page will reload.  Again I am having problems though, this code achieves the disabled part, however the issue is that it's automatically setting all checkboxes to checked:

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
            if ($(".checked").prop('checked', true)) {                
                $('.checked').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `id` attributes *must* be unique within the DOM. To fix your problem, change that `id` to a `class`. Then you can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to only amend the state of the checkbox which raised the event. Try this:

```
<td>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(j => j.PaymentRefundData[i].NotInUse, new { @class = "checked" })
</td>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.checked', function () {
  if (this.checked) this.disabled = true;
});
```

One thing to note is that if the user accidentally checks a box you are not providing them any way to undo their action; the box will be disabled and therefore readonly.

Comment: It's hard to suggest alternatives as you've not told us what you want to achieve. You're correct in that disabled elements will not be included in any form submissions, though.

Comment: I am thinking instead of disable on click, disable any checked checkboxes on page load. Thanks

Comment: `$(':checkbox:checked').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are using an id selector which should be unique to an element `$(document).on('click', '#checked', function (){ ...}`, try using a class selector instead, your code should now look something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.checked', function () {
        if ($(".checked").prop('checked', true)) {  
            $('.checked').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

don't forget to also use classes instead of id in your html.